# OLAP calculated member - summary is wrong

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I would like to ask your support to make olap calculation in my cube with sum aggregation. Currently it is working, when I don't use more dimensions in pivot filter. When I filter for example by other attribute of item dimension (project number), the calculated member provides us the same result in grand total (as before the filter). The code can be found here:

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Invoiced amount YTD on price level YTD PY] AS 
    IIF
    (
      IsLeaf([Item].[Item].CurrentMember)
     ,IIF
      (
          measures.[Average price YTD PY] = 0
        OR 
          IsEmpty(measures.[Average price YTD PY])
       ,
        measures.[Average price YTD] * measures.[Invoiced quantity YTD]
       ,
        measures.[Average price YTD PY] * measures.[Invoiced quantity YTD]
      )
     ,Sum
      (
        [Item].[Item].CurrentMember.Children
       ,[Invoiced amount YTD on price level YTD PY]
      )
    ) 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = '#,##0.00' 
   ,VISIBLE = 1 
   ,ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'PI' ;
```

Comment: to diagnose what is happening can you make a dummy set using just `[Item].[Item].CurrentMember.Children` ... maybe this is not returning what you expect?

Comment: could you please help me to create this dummy set? I never used this kind of solution and I'm not familiar with sets in olap.